# Python: How to be notified when the subprocess is ended opened by Popen

Tags: python, popen

I am using Popen to run a command but I don't know how I can write a callback that gets called once the command is finished. Any idea?

Thanks.
Bin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python subprocess: callback when cmd exits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581817/python-subprocess-callback-when-cmd-exits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `communicate()`:

```
 p = subprocess.Popen('find . -name "*.txt"', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
 stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

You can also call `wait()`, but this might cause problems if the child process fills its output buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use p.poll() method of the Popen object.

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll