# Files opened in subprocess shell

Tags: python, subprocess

At the end of the execution of the following script, I receive some errors like these:

```
filename.enc: No such file or directory
140347508795048:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('filename.enc','r')
140347508795048:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
```

It seems like Popen is trying to close the file at the end of execution, although it was removed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess, os

infile = "filename.enc"
outfile = "filename.dec"
opensslCmd = "openssl enc -a -d -aes-256-cbc -in %s -out %s" % (infile, outfile)   
subprocess.Popen(opensslCmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
os.remove(infile)
```

How can I close the file properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it sounds like your subprocess executes, but since it is non-blocking, your `os.remove(infile)` executes immediately after, deleting the file before the subprocess finishes.

you could use [`subprocess.call()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) instead, which will wait for the command to finish.

... or you could change your code to use [`wait()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(opensslCmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
p.wait()
os.remove(infile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the subprocess.Popen in a thread, and just deleting the file after the subprocess call returned.

see: [Python subprocess: callback when cmd exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581817/python-subprocess-callback-when-cmd-exits)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this.

```
ss=subprocess.Popen(FileName,shell=True)
ss.communicate()
```