# Control the number of subprocesses using to call external commands in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, subprocess, multiprocessing

I understand using [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) is the preferred way of calling external command.

But what if I want to run several commands in parall, but limit the number of processes being spawned? What bothers me is that I can't block the subprocesses. For example, if I call

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=outputfile, stdout=outputfile)
```

Then the process will continue, without waiting for `cmd` to finish. Therefore, I can't wrap it up in a worker of `multiprocessing` library.

For example, if I do:

```
def worker(cmd): 
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=outputfile, stdout=outputfile);

pool = Pool( processes = 10 );
results =[pool.apply_async(worker, [cmd]) for cmd in cmd_list];
ans = [res.get() for res in results];
```

then each worker will finish and return after spawning a subprocess. So I can't really limit the number of processes generated by `subprocess` by using `Pool`.

What's the proper way of limiting the number of subprocesses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.call` if you want to wait for the command to complete.  See [`pydoc subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) for more information.

You could also call the [`Popen.wait`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) method in your worker:

```
def worker(cmd): 
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=outputfile, stdout=outputfile);
    p.wait()
```

---

Because there seems to be some confusion about this answer, here's a complete example:

```
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing
import random
import subprocess


def worker(workerid):
    print(f"start {workerid}")
    p = subprocess.Popen(["sleep", f"{random.randint(1,30)}"])
    p.wait()
    print(f"stop {workerid}")
    return workerid


def main():
    tasks = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as pool:
        for i in range(20):
            tasks.append(pool.submit(worker, i))

        print("waiting for tasks...", flush=True)
        for task in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tasks):
            print(f"completed {task.result()}", flush=True)
        print("done.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you run the above code, you will see that all of the `worker` processes start *in parallel* and that we are able to gather values as they are completed.

Comment: This disables parallel processing completely

Comment: It shouldn't.  The question is using the `multiprocessing` module, and each worker is spawned in a separate process, so `wait()`ing in one worker will not prevent other workers from running.  That said, this isn't correct by itself -- this example doesn't `return` anything from the worker, so calling `.get()` on the results won't return anything.

Comment: Nope, the wait blocks and the other workers are spawned after it returns. [This example demonstrates, that the second command runs after the first one even though the first is very slow.](https://paste.ee/p/pwaXV)

Comment: Does nobody read the comments? It *does not* block the other workers, the `wait()` is running *in a worker subprocess*. @asynts I will update the answer just for you with a complete example.

Comment: I see what you mean and removed the downvote.

Answer (score 19):

You don't need multiple Python processes or even threads to limit maximum number of parallel subprocesses:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT

groups = [(Popen(cmd, stdout=outputfile, stderr=STDOUT)
          for cmd in commands)] * limit # itertools' grouper recipe
for processes in izip_longest(*groups): # run len(processes) == limit at a time
    for p in filter(None, processes):
        p.wait()
```

See [Iterate an iterator by chunks (of n) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8991553/4279)

If you'd like to limit both maximum and minimum number of parallel subprocesses, you could use a thread pool:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from subprocess import STDOUT, call

def run(cmd):
    return cmd, call(cmd, stdout=outputfile, stderr=STDOUT)

for cmd, rc in ThreadPool(limit).imap_unordered(run, commands):
    if rc != 0:
        print('{cmd} failed with exit status: {rc}'.format(**vars()))
```

As soon as any of `limit` subprocesses ends, a new subprocess is started to maintain `limit` number of subprocesses at all times.

Or using [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor # pip install futures
from subprocess import STDOUT, call

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=limit) as executor:
    for cmd in commands:
        executor.submit(call, cmd, stdout=outputfile, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Here's a simple thread pool implementation:

```
import subprocess
from threading import Thread

try: from queue import Queue
except ImportError:
    from Queue import Queue # Python 2.x


def worker(queue):
    for cmd in iter(queue.get, None):
        subprocess.check_call(cmd, stdout=outputfile, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

q = Queue()
threads = [Thread(target=worker, args=(q,)) for _ in range(limit)]
for t in threads: # start workers
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for cmd in commands:  # feed commands to threads
    q.put_nowait(cmd)

for _ in threads: q.put(None) # signal no more commands
for t in threads: t.join()    # wait for completion
```

To avoid premature exit, add exception handling.

If you want to capture subprocess' output in a string, see [Python: execute cat subprocess in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23611396/4279).