# Problem with calling WINDOWS cmd.exe by using subprocess module: fail to control parallel process limitation

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

I am now working on Python, writing a code that need to call **WINDOWS `cmd.exe`** with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html.).

I would like to run thousands of processes continuously but only 6 or less processes running at the same time.

Article [Control the number of subprocesses using to call external commands in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808714/) provides solutions and it seemed work fine on calling programs like Remote Desktop or something, a new program appears after one closed. But I got problem when I apply these codes on calling `cmd.exe`. Codes are below:

```py
import subprocess
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

def worker(cmd): 
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, );
    p.wait()

commands = ['C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe',
            'C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe',
            'C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe',
            'C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe',
            'C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe',]

pool = Pool( processes = 2 );
results =[pool.apply_async(worker, [cmd]) for cmd in commands];
ans = [res.get() for res in results];
This works fine. A new window shows when  one another closed.
```

This code works fine.

But if the processes were cmd.exe

```py
import subprocess
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

def worker(cmd): 
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, );
    p.wait()

commands = ['cmd.exe /c start "Test1" /d E:\pyworkspace\FAST\ FAST_RV_W64.exe 334.in',
            'cmd.exe /c start "Test2" /d E:\pyworkspace\FAST\ FAST_RV_W64.exe 893.in',
            'cmd.exe /c start "Test3" /d E:\pyworkspace\FAST\ FAST_RV_W64.exe 9527.in',
            'cmd.exe /c start "Test4" /d E:\pyworkspace\FAST\ FAST_RV_W64.exe 114514.in',
            'cmd.exe /c start "Test5" /d E:\pyworkspace\FAST\ FAST_RV_W64.exe 1919810.in']

pool = Pool( processes = 2 );
results =[pool.apply_async(worker, [cmd]) for cmd in commands];
ans = [res.get() for res in results];
```

*FAST_RV_64.exe is one of my tool program and *.in is setting file.
With calling `cmd.exe`, all cmd windows jumped out at the same time and the limitation didn't work.

```py
import subprocess
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

def worker(cmd): 
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, );
    p.wait()

commands = ['cmd.exe /c start "Test1" mstsc.exe',
            'cmd.exe /c start "Test2" mspaint.exe',
            'cmd.exe /c start "Test3" SnippingTool.exe',
            'cmd.exe /c start "Test4" mstsc.exe',
            'cmd.exe /c start "Test5" mspaint.exe']

pool = Pool( processes = 2 );
results =[pool.apply_async(worker, [cmd]) for cmd in commands];
ans = [res.get() for res in results];
```

If I called program through `cmd.exe`, it jumps out together, too.

I also tried other method in article above, but no one works.

I wonder why this happened and how can I fix my code.

Comment: why are you running through `cmd.exe` rather than just directly?

Comment: @sam-mason Running `cmd.exe` shows the same result as running `FAST_RV_64.exe` directly. `cmd.exe` starts automatically after `FAST_RV_64.exe` executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That usage of `apply_async()` looks a little suspect – how about `imap_unordered()` instead?

Also, `cmd` + `start` doesn't necessarily wait for the subcommand to exit, so that may also be part of your problem.

How about something like this?

```py
import subprocess
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool


def worker(file):
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        [r"E:\pyworkspace\FAST\FAST_RV_W64.exe", file],
        cwd=r"E:\pyworkspace\FAST",
    )
    p.wait()


files = [
    "334.in",
    "893.in",
    "9527.in",
    "114514.in",
    "1919810.in",
]

with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(worker, files):
        pass
```

Comment: My problem can be solved with this code. But I would like to know is there any way to make every process worked in individual window?

Comment: It really depends on what FAST_RV_W64 does with its console(s) or window(s).

Answer (score 0):

from what you've said, there is no need to run the `cmd` or `start` programs here. just remove them from your command lines, they're not doing anything.

you're unnecessarily running two extra programs (`cmd`, `start`) when only one is necessary (your program)

if you really want to make your computer do this extra work, you can pass the `/wait` flag to `start`, which the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) describe as:

> Starts an application and waits for it to end.

but, given what you wrote in your question, you're much better off just running your program directly

Comment: Sorry for not expressing clearly, what I'm trying to express is that applying `cmd.exe` is probably necessary because the tool program is a kind of program with CLI, it open up a `cmd.exe` right after start and begin running codes. So if I can solve the "`cmd.exe` starts together problem", perhaps I can solve my problem with this tool.