# Terminate subprocess running in thread on program exit

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

Based on the accepted answer to this question: [python-subprocess-callback-when-cmd-exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581817/python-subprocess-callback-when-cmd-exits) I am running a subprocess in a separate thread and after the completion of the subprocess a callable is executed. All good, but the problem is that even if running the thread as a daemon, the subprocess continues to run even after the program exits normally or it is killed by `kill -9`, Ctrl + C, etc...

Below is a very simplified example (runs on 2.7):

```
import threading
import subprocess
import time
import sys


def on_exit(pid):
    print 'Process with pid %s ended' % pid

def popen_with_callback(cmd):

    def run_in_thread(command):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            command,
            shell=False
        )
        proc.wait()
        on_exit(proc.pid)
        return

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_in_thread, args=([cmd]))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    return thread

if __name__ == '__main__':
    popen_with_callback(
        [
            "bash", 
            "-c",
            "for ((i=0;i<%s;i=i+1)); do echo $i; sleep 1; done" % sys.argv[1]
        ])
    time.sleep(5)
    print 'program ended'
```

If the main thread lasts longer than the subprocess everything is fine:

```
(venv)~/Desktop|➤➤ python testing_threads.py 3
> 0
> 1
> 2
> Process with pid 26303 ended
> program ended
```

If the main thread lasts less than the subprocess, the subprocess continues to run until it eventually hangs:

```
(venv)~/Desktop|➤➤ python testing_threads.py 8
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> program ended
(venv)~/Desktop|➤➤ 5
> 6
> 7
# hanging from now on
```

How to terminate the subprocess if the main program is finished or killed? I tried to use `atexit.register(os.kill(proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM))` just before `proc.wait` but it actually executes when the thread running the subprocess exits, not when the **main** thread exits.

I was also thinking of polling for the parent pid, but I am not sure how to implement it because of the `proc.wait` situation.

Ideal outcome would be:

```
(venv)~/Desktop|➤➤ python testing_threads.py 8
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> program ended
> Process with pid 1234 ended
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Thread.join` method, which blocks main thread until this thread exits:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    popen_with_callback(
        [
            "bash", 
            "-c",
            "for ((i=0;i<%s;i=i+1)); do echo $i; sleep 1; done" % sys.argv[1]
        ]).join()
    print 'program ended'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got an ugly but effective method.
Just set a global variable to handle the proc=subprocess.Popen(),
and you can kill the proc whenever you like:

```
my_proc = None

def popen_with_callback(cmd):
  def run_in_thread(command):
    global my_proc
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False)
    my_proc = proc
    proc.wait()
    on_exit(proc.pid)
    return
...
```

Then you can kill the proc wherever you want in the program.
just do:

```
my_proc.kill()
```