# Accessing user home directory from django

Tags: python, django, unix, authentication, subprocess

I'm creating a Django app who can access to the user home directory. For this purpose I want to create a directory using something like `os.mkdir('/home/user/new_directory')` or a *subprocess* command.

Because Django is started by an apache server, python act as the apache user and can't access to my users home directories.

Currently, I know the login of my users because they have to be logged on the website. Is there a solution to **perform unix commands from Django/Python in the name of the user** ?

Comment: A user account on the webapp means a different thing from a user on the machine that serves the webapp.  There may be even many different machines that serve the same webapp..

Comment: In my case I use an unified decentralized authentication system between the webapps and the different accessible servers in my network. It's transparent for a unix authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the home directories via `MEDIA_URL` /or symlink itself.
I think of a combined aproach of symlink and os.system calls.

[what-is-symlinking-and-how-can-learn-i-how-to-to-do-this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68368/what-is-symlinking-and-how-can-learn-i-how-to-to-do-this)

To change the apache user, use `os.system(su <command>)`
[changing-user-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025294/changing-user-in-python)

Comment: This way doesn't really change the user to perform the command. The user is changed during the `os.system()` call only. The whole command with credentials has to be set in during the call : `os.system("echo %s | su %s -c 'bash command' " % (password, username))`.