# Run os.system as if python was not executed with sudo

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.system, notify-send

When I run the following command, everyhting works as expected. No error and I get a system notification saying "Hello":

```
$ python3
>>> import os
>>> os.system("notify-send Hello")
0
```

However, when I do this:

```
$ sudo python3
>>> import os
>>> os.system("notify-send Hello")
```

The script gets stuck and nothing happens.

I then tried to do this:

```
$ sudo python3
>>> import os
>>> os.seteuid(1000)
>>> os.system("notify-send Hello")
```

(`1000` being my normal non-root user account)
But still, the script gets stuck and nothing happens.

I also tried this:

```
$ sudo python3
>>> import os
>>> os.system("su my-user-name -c 'notify-send Hello'")
```

and this:

```
$ sudo python3
>>> import os
>>> os.seteuid(1000)
>>> os.system("su my-user-name -c 'notify-send Hello'")
```

They all have the same issue...

I'm not looking for an alternative way of creating notifications. I'm not interested in `subprocess` or things like `notify2` which cause a whole new category of problems on my system. Oh and please don't tell me not to use sudo. I have my reasons.

Comment: `subprocess` is the preferred way to start new processes; what problem does it give you that `os.system` does not?

Comment: It causes `notify-send` to throw errors.

Comment: *What* errors? That's probably what you should be asking about.

Comment: You should use `subprocess`. Why are you "not interested" in it?

Comment: @chepner I can't remember. Maybe I'll ask another question addressing that issue. For now I'm just curious how this problem can be solved using os.system or if it is simply not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing user in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025294/changing-user-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation detail I've discovered through trial-and-error is `notify-send` requires the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment variable to function -- at least with these versions:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep libnotify
ii  libnotify-bin                              0.7.7-3                                      amd64        sends desktop notifications to a notification daemon (Utilities)
ii  libnotify4:amd64                           0.7.7-3                                      amd64        sends desktop notifications to a notification daemon
```

I first determined it needed some sort of environment variable by using `env -i notify-send hello`, which produced no notification.

I then bisected the environment with a modified version of [this script](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/blob/master/python/minimal_environment.py)

How you get that environment variable is up to you, but you need to be running `notify-send` as the proper user and with that variable set.

Here's a sample python script, I refuse to use `os.system` due to its security issues:

```
import os
import pwd
import subprocess
import sys


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        raise SystemExit(f'usage `{sys.argv[0]} USER`')
    if os.getuid() != 0:
        raise SystemExit('expected to run as root')

    # find the `gnome-session` executable, we'll use that to grab
    # XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
    cmd = ('pgrep', '-u', sys.argv[1], 'gnome-session')
    pid = int(subprocess.check_output(cmd))

    # read that process's environment
    with open(f'/proc/{pid}/environ') as f:
        for line in f.read().split('\0'):
            if line.startswith('XDG_RUNTIME_DIR='):
                _, _, xdg_runtime_dir = line.partition('=')
                break
        else:
            raise SystemExit('Could not find XDG_RUNTIME_DIR')

    # run the notify send as the right user
    uid = pwd.getpwnam(sys.argv[1]).pw_uid
    os.seteuid(uid)
    os.environ['XDG_RUNTIME_DIR'] = xdg_runtime_dir
    os.execvp('notify-send', ('notify-send', 'ohai'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(main())
```

***DISCLAIMER***: this script is doing some very hacky things that I wouldn't necessarily suggest in production code.  Notably:

- shelling out to pgrep to find a process
- reading another process's environment variables
- `sudo`

Sample usage:

```
$ python3 t.py
usage `t.py USER`
$ python3 t.py asottile
expected to run as root
$ sudo python3 t.py asottile
# (I get a notification for `ohai`)
```