# running a process as a different user from Python

Tags: python, linux, popen

I am running a script as `userA` with root access, from this script I want to make a `popen()` call and run a different process as `userB`.

os.setuid() does not seem to work for this (unless I am doing this wrong?), and I would like to avoid a linux based solution such as `su -userB -c <command>`

Is there a pythonic way of running a process as `userB` while the script is running as `userA`?

Comment: The following answer has a really nice approach for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6037494/505154

Comment: +1 for @F.J. Same approach I use in my own code.

Comment: +1 as well for @F.J that works great! If you want to summarize the answer here I'd be happy to give you a bit of rep and the answer credit as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following answer has a really nice approach for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6037494/505154

There is a working code example there, but the summary is to use `subprocess.Popen()` with a `preexec_fn` to set up the environment of the subprocess so that it executes as another user.

Comment: In new versions of Python 3, it's as simple as adding the user argument to any subprocess method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69560149/6296967