# Running a portion of code as NON-root?

Tags: python-2.7, root, sudo, python-webbrowser

My program runs with root privileges, but I need a portion to run as an unprivileged user.

Basically, webbrowser.open(SITE) doesn't work as root. My code needs to run as root other than this. I've tried the following:

```
subprocess.call("sudo -u " + getpass.getuser() + " " + webbrowser.open("https://github.com/codywd/WiFiz/issues"))
```

It causes the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 364, in OnReport
    subprocess.call("sudo -u " + getpass.getuser() + " " + webbrowser.open("https://github.com/codywd/WiFiz/issues"))
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'bool' objects
START /usr/bin/chromium "https://github.com/codywd/WiFiz/issues"
[7250:7250:0201/231848:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_gtk.cc(50)] Startup refusing to run as root.
```

I understand WHY this error is happening, but I don't know how else to execute this code.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answers given here are what you are looking for:
[Run child processes as different user from a long running Python process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770209/run-child-processes-as-different-user-from-a-long-running-process)

However, since I can not find a way to directly access the subprocess started inside the webbrowser.open (see doc on http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html), you have two options:

- drop the webbrowser module from your code, open the browser via
  subprocess calls. On this you can set UID and GID bits.
- set a wrapper arround the webbrowser (expanded below)

1. Create a new python script, start normally webbrowser.open from there.
2. Inside your main program create a subprocess, with the right UID + GID, this will call your wrapper script described at 1).