# design pattern for logging from a web server worker as an unprivileged user in python

Tags: python, linux, process, webserver, init

The design pattern for spawning web server workers seems to be that they are started by root in an init script and then spawn a process as an unprivileged user. For example, I start a gunicorn web server daemon in an init script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

$LOGFILE=/var/log/gunicorn.error.log
$PIDFILE=/var/run/gunicorn.pid

[...]
gunicorn -u nobody -b 127.0.0.1:8000 \
    --error-logfile=$LOGFILE --pidfile=$PIDFILE -D
```

I can spawn my own scripts as an unprivileged user (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770209/run-child-processes-as-different-user-from-a-long-running-process)), but that process can no longer write log files to `/var/log`.

How do I enable a worker spawned by a `root` process to write log files to `/var/log` and PID files to `/var/run`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By creating a folder for your process inside the `/var/log` and `/var/run` folders, you can change the owner and group from within the init script (as it's ran by root), so the process will have write access to it. For `/var/log`, it is enough to create the folder once, but the `/var/run` folder will have to be recreated on every system restart. This is how I solved it (for simplicity I recreate here both folders):

```
DAEMON_USER='unprivilegeduser'
DAEMON_GROUP='unprivilegedgroup'
DAEMON_PID_DIR='/var/run/myprocessname'
DAEMON_LOG_DIR='/var/log/myprocessname'
PIDFILE="$DAEMON_PID_DIR/gunicorn.pid"
LOGFILE="$DAEMON_LOG_DIR/gunicorn.error.log"

mkdir -p $DAEMON_PID_DIR
mkdir -p $DAEMON_LOG_DIR
chown $DAEMON_USER:$DAEMON_GROUP $DAEMON_PID_DIR
chown $DAEMON_USER:$DAEMON_GROUP $DAEMON_LOG_DIR

[...]
gunicorn -u nobody -b 127.0.0.1:8000 \
    --error-logfile=$LOGFILE --pidfile=$PIDFILE -D
```