# Python Run as different user

Tags: python, passwords, credentials, windows-server-2012-r2

On windows server I need via python code to run an executable/process (such as a notepad \ ps1 script) with other domain user privilages. The credntials are hardcoded in the python script. The script should run remotelly on the server so the password promt is problematic. Is there any way I can open a proccess with known cerentials (user + password) without code interuption?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run child processes as different user from a long running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770209/run-child-processes-as-different-user-from-a-long-running-process)

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2